# VSTS 2k8 crash causes project lock (as in checked out for edit)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My laptop crashed this morning, badly, and I spent most of the day running HDD checks and I'm now back on track, to a degree. Anyway, VS now seems to think that my projects are checked out by source control (I have VSTS 2k8) and will not allow me to add anything to the project. I can open and edit existing files, and even there it's quirky with the keyboard, but that's about it.

I tried repairing VS, but that didn't fix the issue. I also tried giving the Users group full control over the project files, but that also didn't work.

So, does anyone know how I can get VS to unlock the project(s)? I don't want to sit down and rewrite everything into a new project just so I can continue development...

Answer (score 0):

I would copy all the sources to a backup folder, delete the original, and take everything again from the source-control. (open from source-control)
If there is non-committed files, and you know which one, copy the changes manually after the VS and the SC are synced.

(most SC has option to break/steal locks, if the SC thinks someone else is "checking out" the files).

Comment: That's just the thing, these projects were never put into source control... I'll try what you've suggested and I hope it works... Back in 5...

Comment: Well, I tried. I nuked the files, restarted, restored (from a RAR), and I got the same thing again... Not sure where to go next...

Comment: if the files where never in source control, I don't understand the problem. does the source control refuse to add them ?